# force primeng dropdown to pop up

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, primeng

Is there any way to force a primeng dropdown to show the options on top, drop up not as drop down, as the drop down makes scroll inside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 13):

Use `appendTo="body"` on dropdown to avoid scroll( *assuming that its scroll on parent element* ). Where to show popup is calculated depending on the position of dropdown in screen, better dont mess with that. You don't want to show pop "up" when the control is already at the top of screen.

```
<p-dropdown appendTo="body" [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: @kknair Can you mark this answer as correct(tick). It worked for me too!

Comment: @Vimalraj the suggested solution does not generically force the drop down to go up, so I would not mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: This force dropdown to always on top to avoid parent scroll

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! Primeng doesn't even have this in their docs.